# Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue and angular $http service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Sorry for duplicating a question for this issue but I really tried to seek for a solution but I could not find it. So I use angular $http.get xhr request to retrieve data from the public api. I have next code

```
 $http.get('http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getMakes&year=2000&sold_in_us=1')
     .success(function(d){ console.log(d); })
     .error(function(d){ console.log( "nope" ); 
 });
```

this returns in console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getMakes&year=2009. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'blah-my-localhost-blah' is therefore not allowed access.
```

However if I user jquery getJson method it works just fine:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?", {cmd:"getMakes", year:"2009"},                      
  function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

So obviously I can configure angular to send correct request since jQuery works fine?

Thank you for the response.

Comment: Jquery getJSON is using jsonp since callback parameter exists in url

Comment: angular doesn't use `?` for the callback the way jQuery does...read docs for proper callback string and use `$http.jsonp`  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [$http.jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) method to do a jsonp request along with **JSON_CALLBACK** as the callback name:

```
$http.jsonp('http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&cmd=getMakes&year=2000&sold_in_us=1')
     .success(function(d){ console.log(d); })
     .error(function(d){ console.log( "nope" ); });
```

Comment: What does that strange `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` parameter do? Some explanation would be appreciated.